# IronRuby System.DateTime NilClass

Tags: .net, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

Why comparing to null is so unstable?

Just code.

```
IronRuby 0.9.4.0 on .NET 2.0.50727.4927
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

>>> require 'System'
=> true
>>> i = System::Int32.MinValue
=> -2147483648
>>> i==nil
=> false
>>> d = System::DateTime.Now
=> 11.02.2010 14:15:02
>>> d==nil
(ir):1: can't convert NilClass into System::DateTime (TypeError)
>>>
```

In 9.1 this code works as expected.

**EDIT:**

workaround:

```
>>> i.nil?
=> false
>>> d.nil?
=> false
>>> nil
=> nil
>>> nil.nil?
=> true
>>>
```

Comment: This is now a workaround. This is how you regulary check for nulity in Ruby.

Comment: @Shay Friedman WTF is not in checking, it is in _inconsistency_

Comment: +1 for "WTF" in the question.

Comment: +1 We should fill in a bug to IronRuby Team. I understand that DateTime in .NET (CLR) can't be null too only MinValue and MaxValue. unless implement the Nullable type. but it should work as Integer.

Comment: @Jirapong yes, sure http://ironruby.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=3930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the inconsistency is because `System.DateTime` defines it's own == method, and `System.Int32` does not.
Furthermore, `System.Int32` is a "special" class in that IronRuby maps it directly to `Fixnum`, so when you call `System.Int32 == x`, you're actually calling the built in `Fixnum#==` method.

With that in mind, here's what happens:

With `Int32`, which maps to `Fixnum`

```
x = System::Int32.MinValue # => -2147483648
x.class # => Fixnum
x == nil # => Fixnum == nil
```

With `Int16` which doesn't map to anything, and does not overload `==`

```
x = System::Int16.MinValue # => -32768 (Int16)
x.class # => System::Int16
x == nil # => Object == nil
```

With `DateTime` which doesn't map, but *does* overload `==`

```
x = System::DateTime.Now # => 1/03/2010 9:00:47 a.m.
x.class # => System::DateTime
x == nil # System::DateTime == nil
```

The `System::DateTime` overloaded `==` method only accepts other `System::DateTime` structures.
IronRuby then tries to convert `nil` to one of these structures so it can call the method, which then fails with the error you see.

Does this appear inconsistent? Yes.
Is it actually inconsistent? I'd argue no. Well, no more inconsistent than any other CLR type that defines it's own `==` method. To me it makes no sense to just have a special case for `System::DateTime`

In general though, it doesn't matter. The "correct" way to check for null in ruby is to call `.nil?`, and this works well with `DateTime` or any other class/struct

Comment: @Orion Edwards yes u r right it all about mapping. But it is definitely a bug, null checking should be safe in ruby. See codeplex link for comment from Jimmy. I mark your answer as right though :)

Comment: I don't see any comment from Jimmy on that Codeplex link? The only comment I see is from Tomas, who basically says the same thing that I did

Comment: oh, sorry. yes, Comment from Tomas. But issue status changed to Active by Jimmy Schementi and it is planned to _change_